# Akka Source that emits when another Sink receives

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I have a source `a` that emits values into a sink `b`.

Now I want to have another source `c` that emits a value, everytime b receives an event.

My idea was to use another sink `d` that can be used as a notifier, but then I need the functionality to create a Source from a Sink.

`a.to(b).alsoTo(d)`

something like

`Source.from(d)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of describing this is that you want every event emitted by `a` to go to both `b` and `c`. This is what a `BroadcastHub` does; it can be used to allow events from one `Source` to be consumed by multiple `Sinks`.

If you connect a `Source` to a `BroadcastHub.sink` and then materialise it, you get a new `Source`. This `Source` can then be attached to 2 or more `Sink`s and each `Sink` will get a copy of the message sent by the original `Source`.

For example I use this with Akka to have a Actor that broadcasts messages to multiple clients (for gRPC events):

```
val (actorRef: ActorRef[Event], eventSource: Source[Event, akka.NotUsed]) =
  ActorSource.actorRef[Event](
    completionMatcher = PartialFunction.empty,
    failureMatcher = PartialFunction.empty,
    16,
    OverflowStrategy.fail
  )
    .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink)(Keep.both)
    .run()
```

This creates `eventSource` which can be used in a pipeline and materialised multiple times to create multiple streams. Each time a message is sent to the `actorRef`, every stream that was materialised from `eventSource` receives that message.

See [the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#using-the-broadcasthub) for more details.